# How can I restart kivy animation every time its called upon?

Tags: python, function, animation, kivy, widget

I am making a simple weather app. The user enters a location and gets results in plain text. I have made a loading screen that has a spinning animation. When the program is loading these weather results, it changes to the loading screen and the animation spins well.

I have the animation set for a duration of 20 seconds for now. This allows the first instance of my load screen display more than enough time to yield results and then change to the results screen (normally about 5 seconds). That seemingly works well.

My issue is: Once the animation has completed its 20 second run (in the background) it doesn't re start when called for again. It seems the app will allow it to be called once only. For it to animate again, the app must be closed completely and restarted.

Ideally I'd like the animation to stop spinning and be reset as soon as the load screen has been exited (so once the results have been delivered). The user can get weather multiple times, so I need it to start again every time the load screen is displayed.

I have tried the undesired solution of having it constantly spinning in the background so that when the load screen is shown, its spinning.

But, even then I am having trouble getting it to repeat... (`anim.repeat = True` doesn't work for me)

Here is a working example that has been stripped back as much as possible to still behave the same as my real app.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation
import time
from threading import Thread

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class Results1Screen(Screen):
    pass
class LoadScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def spin_widget(self):
        widget = self.root.ids["load_screen"].ids["spinning_widget"]
        anim = Animation(angle=-2000, duration=20)
        anim.repeat = True # this doesn't seem to work?
        anim.start(widget)

    def thread1(self): # this starts the actual "work" of the app by calling get_briefing() below
        p2 = Thread(target=lambda: self.get_briefing())
        p2.start()

    def get_briefing(self):
        time.sleep(5)# I have added a 5sec sleep to emulate work being done
        self.change_screen("results_1_screen") # screen change from loading screen to results screen after work complete
TestApp().run()
```

main.kv (just for screen managing)

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:include kv/homescreen.kv
#:include kv/results1screen.kv
#:include kv/loadscreen.kv
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        Results1Screen:
            name: "results_1_screen"
            id: results_1_screen
        LoadScreen:
            name: "load_screen"
            id: load_screen
```

homescreen.kv

```
<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000523")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Button:
        text: "GO!"
        pos_hint:  {"top": .2, "center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .5, .08
        padding: 20, 20
        on_release:
            app.spin_widget()
            app.change_screen("load_screen") # widget spinning and going to load screen
            app.thread1() # start the app working in background
```

results1screen.kv (in real app, this has desired results displayed)

```
<Results1Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000523")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text: "RESULTS"
        pos_hint: {"top": .9, "center_x": .5}
        size_hint: 1, .1
    Button:
        text: "back"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        on_release:
            app.change_screen("home_screen")
```

loadscreen.kv

```
<LoadScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000523")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            text: "loading"
        SpinningWidget:
            id: spinning_widget
            angle: 0
            size_hint: .1, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
<SpinningWidget@Image>
    angle: 0
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
```

I have tried a couple of ways of exiting or resetting the spin widget function after the `get_briefing` function has finished but to no avail. I have tried `anim.cancel()` and things like `exit(self.spin_widget())` in an attempt to reset it, ready for its next call up.

Can someone please help me out, I can't seem to find an answer in Kivy docs or anywhere else online for that matter. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because in its current state, the question is very hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you @0dminnimda for your feedback. I have edited my original to make the example as minimalistic as possible while still remaining functional and showing the same problems as the original app. I have edited my description and questions too in the hopes it will be more easily understood. Please let me know if I can do more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the `angle` to `0` before each `Animation`:

```
def spin_widget(self):
    widget = self.root.ids["load_screen"].ids["spinning_widget"]
    widget.angle = 0
    anim = Animation(angle=-2000, duration=20)
    anim.repeat = True # this doesn't seem to work?
    anim.start(widget)
```

The problem is that after the first `Animation`, the `angle` value is `-2000`, so any `Animation` after that will not actually change the angle. Same problem with `repeat`.

Comment: That works perfectly now @John Anderson! Thank you so much! If I may ask one more question... If leave it on repeat (in case a loading session takes over 20sec) and I wanted to have the animation stop spinning (once the loading session was over) should I make reference to 'widget.angle' again? Or is there a better way to stop it? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: In order for `repeat` to work, your `anim` must be a sequence, like `anim=Animation(...) + Animation(...)` where the second `Animation` typically is the reverse of the first. Another way is to use the `on_complete` event to bind another method that resets `angle` and starts another `Animation`.

Comment: Thanks so much John